# Facebook SDK for Android list groups which a user is member of?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the latest version of Facebook Android SDK and I can't find a way to retrieve the user groups list, because the call to

```
/{user-id}/groups
```

gives me only groups where the user has administrator privilegies.

Any way to get the **complete** list of groups?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get ALL groups anymore, you can only get the groups you manage.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4